# D3 transition works unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, d3.js, string-interpolation

For some reason, D3 is not transitioning the div's width smoothing on exit.

In the GIF below, I switch between 2 datasets, from `[20, 40]` to `[20]`

The expected behavior is that the blue div should shrink smoothly, but instead, it gets stuck.

what should I do differently?

[image: demo]

**Live example:** http://jsbin.com/vikodufugo/1/edit?js,output

```
const render = (data) => {
  const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'gold'];
  const width = (data) => (d) => (d / d3.max(data)) * 100 + '%';

  const selection = d3
    .select('.chart')
    .selectAll('div')
    .data(data);

  selection
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .style('width', width(data))

  selection
    .enter()
    .append('div')
    .style('width', '0px')
    .style('height', '100px')
    .style('background-color', (d, i) => colors[i % colors.length])
    .transition()
      .duration(750)
      .style('width', width(data))

  selection
    .exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    // shouldn't it transition smoothly?
    .style('width', '0px')
    .remove()
}

...

onClick('#button-1', () => render([20, 40]))
onClick('#button-2', () => render([20]))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is just the interpolation used by the transition.

D3 can interpolate two strings without any problem, for instance `300px` to `20px`. However, in your case, the start string has a `"%"` while the final string has `"px"`. D3 cannot interpolate that, which is quite excusable: what's the transition from `"%"` to `"px"`?

Let's show it in the following snippets. Here, I'm using [d3.interpolateString(a,b)](https://github.com/d3/d3-interpolate/blob/master/README.md#interpolateString), which:

> Returns an interpolator between the two strings a and b. The string interpolator finds numbers embedded in a and b, where each number is of the form understood by JavaScript.

In the first demo, both strings have `"px"`:

```js
var interpolator = d3.interpolateString("300px", "0px");
d3.range(0,1.1,.1).forEach(function(d){
 console.log(interpolator(d))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, nice results.

Now look what happens if the first string has `"%"` while the second one has `"px"`:

```js
var interpolator = d3.interpolateString("100%", "0px");
d3.range(0,1.1,.1).forEach(function(d){
 console.log(interpolator(d))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

As you can see, at the very first interpolation, the `"%"` is converted to `"px"`. That explains the behaviour you're seeing: the div goes from `"100%"` to `"100px"` suddenly, and from there to `"0px"` during the transition time.

**Solution**:

Change your string to use `%` in the exit selection:

```
selection
    .exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(750) 
    .style('width', '0%')
    //use % here -----^
    .remove()
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
const render = (data) => {
  const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'gold'];
  const width = (data) => (d) => (d / d3.max(data)) * 100 + '%';

  const selection = d3
    .select('.chart')
    .selectAll('div')
    .data(data);

  selection
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    .style('width', width(data))

  selection
    .enter()
    .append('div')
    .style('width', '0px')
    .style('height', '100px')
    .style('background-color', (d, i) => colors[i % colors.length])
    .transition()
      .duration(750)
      .style('width', width(data))

  selection
    .exit()
    .transition()
    .duration(750)
    // shouldn't it transition smoothly?
    .style('width', '0%')
    .remove()
}


const onClick = (selector, callback) => (
  document.querySelector(selector).addEventListener('click', callback)
);

onClick('#button-1', () => render([20, 40]))
onClick('#button-2', () => render([20]))

render([20, 40]);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script> 
<div class="buttons">
    <button id="button-1" value="0">Option 1</button>
    <button id="button-2" value="1">Option 2</button>
</div>
<div class="chart"></div>
```